# swift defer piculiarity: why is code in case:defer is invoked before the end of the switch scope?

Tags: swift

```
case .foo:
    defer {
       baz()
    }
    fallthrough
case .bar:
```

baz() is reached BEFORE we fall through into the bar scene.
Is that expected or is compiler bork?
I was expecting baz() to get invoked at the end of the switch
scope or function scope???!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end of the `case:` block is the end of the scope of that block... The `fallthrough` statement doesn't maintain the scope.

Consider the following:

```
    defer { print("outer deferred") }

    let t = 1

    switch t {
    case 0:
        print("0")
    case 1:
        print("1")
        defer { print("deferred") }
        fallthrough
    case 2:
        print("2")
    default:
        print("default")
    }
```

The output will be:

> 1
>
> deferred
>
> 2
>
> outer deferred

Now, consider this:

```
    defer { print("outer deferred") }

    let t = 1

    switch t {
    case 0:
        print("0")
    case 1:
        let str = "hello"
        print("1")
        defer { print("deferred") }
        fallthrough
    case 2:
        print("2")
        print(str)        // <-- error
    default:
        print("default")
    }
```

The compiler will tell you that `str` is an unresolved identifier, because it was created inside `case 1:` but is no longer in scope in `case 2:`.